# winutils.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, windows, runtime-error, pyspark

I used pySpark in python and set environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` to point to a folder above `bin\winutils.exe` on a Windows Server 2012 in EC2. I got this error when I tried to run the python script.

Answer (score 4):

The blame is on "Fault Module Name: MSVCR100.dll". you can fix this by downloading Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632